# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Permission denied Error

Tags: react-native

when I log in, I change state value to 'true'.

```
export const isLoggedInVar = makeVar(false);
export const tokenVar = makeVar(“”);
export const logUserIn = async (token) => {
  await AsyncStorage.multiSet([
    [“token”, JSON.stringify(token)],
    [“loggedIn”, JSON.stringify(“yes”)],
  ]);
  tokenVar(token);
  isLoggedInVar(true); ----> **
};
```

And if isLoggedIn state is chagned to `true`, I change screen from `Profile_Login` to `Profile_Logout`.

```
<Tab.Screen
        name=“Profile”
        component={isLoggedIn ? Profile_Login : Profile_Logout}
      />
```

But I keep facing an error message

> :x: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted
> component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
> application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
> in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function,

after googling I realized that it's because I change state even though the change is already changed.

But state is changed -> screen changed.
why it shows an error that state is changed after screen changed..?

and error says i need to use clean up in useEffect to solve this problem.
in this situation, what clean up function means ? and how can I use in useEffect?

especially which screen should i use in `Profile_login` **(screen after change)** or `Profile_logout` **(screen before change)** ?

Comment: can you share your full code ? how do you call `logUserIn` function

Comment: @ucup I use `useReactiveVar`   const isLoggedIn = useReactiveVar(isLoggedInVar);

Comment: have you concider using a useEffect as react native suggest ?

Comment: @ucup I don't know how to use useEffect in this case so I ask how :)

Comment: `useEffect(()=>{  //yourfunction here  }, []) //inside array is dependecy for refteching the effect` but i think the problem here is not useEffect, for login check you need to make a global state to store the data (redux or useContext). in that way when you call logout  function the changes will reflect immediately

Comment: @ucup yes you were right, I solved the problem by using useContext. thanks.